# docker-compose restart on failure

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to automatically **restart a container** (not run an image) when it stops running.

All the examples I see mention `docker run` but I just want to restart a previously created container.

I tried adding the following to the service definition in the yml file, but it didn't do anything:

```
restart: always
```

Comment: What does the container do?  Why did it stop?  How are you trying to restart it?  Have you manually tried commands like `docker-compose start`?  What happens?

Comment: @DavidMaze hi, thank you. The container runs a script and on fail the container stops running, when that happens I manually restart the container by doing 'docker-compose restart', but I want to see if this can be done automatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose `restart: always` didn't do anything because you need to run `docker-compose up` so that it will make a new container with this policy in place. With `restart: always` container will be restarted in any case when it is not running. That is not only after failure but after reboot as well.

Using restart policy is the recommended way to solve this problem but it requires you to recreate the container once to apply the policy. If you can't tolerate even one recreation (there are ways to keep the data: see `docker cp`, `docker commit`), you may get along with a cron script:

```
* * * * * docker ps | grep -q container_name || docker start container_name
```

Once in a minute this will check if the container is up and restart it if it is not.

Snippet for powershell:

```
if ( docker ps | Select-String -quiet container_name ) {} else { docker start container_name }
```

Comment: nice, that's exactly what i was looking for, i actually need it to be restarted between certain hours only so this cron command is exactly what i need

Comment: weird its returning At line:1 char:46
+ docker ps | grep container_name >> /dev/null || docker restart contai ...
+                                              ~~
The token '||' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine

Comment: @RobertSinclair `||` is like an 'OR' statement. Are you using powershell?

Comment: yep doing it in powershell

Comment: @RobertSinclair That's bash syntax, not powershell. For powershell you need something like this: `if (docker ps | Select-String -quiet <container_name>) {} else {docker start <container_name>}`

Comment: You can utilise the docker-compose file to configure this in compose v3: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#deploy

Comment: What is the meaning of "That is not only after failure but after reboot as well."? Container will be restarted after reboot?

Comment: "sub-options only takes effect when deploying to a swarm with docker stack deploy, and is ignored by docker-compose up." So start policy will be not available when I am using `docker-compose up`? @James111

Answer (score 5):

can you try this [docker_restart_policy](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#restart_policy)

```
￼
version: "3.9"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
```

Comment: deploy: section is only accepted in docker swarm deployment, not if you run it as docker-compose up command.

Comment: As of now (25 oct, 23), the `deploy` config exists on compose v3: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#deploy

Comment: Docker-compose will display which keys are not being used because you're not using swarm.

I believe for me, condition and delay work, but max_attempts and window don't.  As such, I ended up using `restart: on-failure:n` because it's a shorter syntax for the args that are supported.